# Simple Servlet Problem

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm using eclipse and GlassFish 3.0 to test my servlet. When I start it eclipse opens a kind of a web browser which gives a 404 error with the description:The requested resource () is not available.

What to do?

Thanks, 
Nahum

Comment: Please provide a little more detail. How did you package the servlet? Were there any deployment error? What is the url you are trying to reach the servlet at?

Answer (score 1):

In the Console view switch to the server log, and *pin it* to avoid the DAS grabbing it back.  You can see the deployment errors in there and take action.

If there is no deployment errors, you should double-check:

- URL - is it right - should you have /mywebapp in front, or not.
- Servlet mapping in web.xml - is it correct?  Are your URL hitting the mapping you've set up.

GlassFish is a bit tricky to work with, but once you've learned the Console trick in Eclipse it helps quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks... The eclipse browser goes to http://localhost:8080/ser1/servlet/ser1.FileServlet (the servlet name is FileServlet). I have a file C:\servlet\ser1\WebContent\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot\index.html and in my web.xml there is a line <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>. I hope that info helps because I realy need some help... @Bobby @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen